# Can my drywall act as an air barrier?

Tags: drywall, insulation

I am preparing to improve a building in a cold climate zone. Since it does not seem to be properly insulated, I am reading a book about insulating and weatherizing. That teaches me that I should create an *airtight* thermal boundary. I have many questions about that, but this one is about the *airtight* aspect in particular.

Although the exterior of the building has largely been neglected, the interior has new drywall installed almost everywhere. Can that drywall act as an air barrier? I have found an article about [the airtight drywall approach](http://www.finehomebuilding.com/how-to/departments/energy-smart-details/airtight-drywall.aspx), but it is not clear to me whether this will be a feasible approach for a situation like mine, where the drywall has already been installed. Somewhere else, I read that "air does not move through most solid objects (concrete blocks and masonry in general are notable exceptions)", so since drywall is not mentioned as exception, that seems to confirm that it should work fine.

In order for a drywall to act as the air barrier, does it need to be a special kind of drywall? Or does it need to be treated with special paint at all? Does anybody have experience with the airtight drywall approach?

Answer (score 4):

Drywall is mostly composed of compressed gypsum and a paper for structural integrity.  For all intents and purposes air will not flow through it if installed correctly, however the importance of being air tight is to control moisture and condensation from forming inside of your walls.  This is where the vapor barrier comes into play.

A vapor barrier to be most effective should be airtight from the outside.  This can be done using appropriate tape and materials that you can get from your local hardware store.  User decker has a great explanation on this here.

https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/25277/6086

Being in a cold climate your inside of the house will be a lot warmer than the outside for most of the year, so condensation will form on the insulation facing the outside. This moisture can result in mold.

If you are certain that there is not correctly installed vapor barrier behind your insulation, then one option is to tear down the drywall to where you can do this.

A better option might be to look at possibly rewrapping the outside of the house in a new wrap and seaming it to help create the air tight situation that you want.  You mentioned that the outside looks in rough shape so perhaps tearing off the siding was in the plans anyway?

**ADDITIONAL NOTE**

You may see that there exists a special moisture resistant drywall product typically called "green board".  This will not help you with moisture inside the wall because the moisture resistant properties of the drywall have to do with the green paper on the front face of the drywall.  The board itself is still composed of gypsum and doesn't have any special moisture resistance by itself without the front paper.  It is intended for installation in bathrooms where it will withstand high moisture environments inside the home.

Comment: Wrapping the exterior does not in any way address the issue of moisture migrating from the interior and condensing in the insulation. It does stop external air infiltration from removing heat from the insulation quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn drywall into an air barrier. But it takes work. You need to caulk the floor and ceiling. You need to use enclosed electrical boxes. You need to seal all electrical boxes around all the holes. And then you have to remember to never put a hole in a wall to hang a picture ;)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Drywall is an air barrier, but on its own it is not sufficient to stop air leakage.

Drywall is a decent air barrier but not a moisture barrier. In cold climates, vapor barriers (such as polyethylene) should be installed between the drywall and the insulation because the interior tends to be more humid than the outdoors. Plywood/OSB sheathing under the siding forms a decent air barrier, too. Housewrap over the sheathing should prevent moisture from entering the wall from the outside while allowing moisture to escape from the wall cavity.

Is the home balloon or platform framed? This will not affect your drywall question, but it will affect the home's air sealing needs. [This DOE graphic](http://energy.gov/sites/prod/files/styles/article_hero/public/airsealing_housemap.jpg?itok=Yn_353f4) shows trouble spots on a platform framed home. In a balloon framed home, the wall, floor, and ceiling cavities are interconnected and allow air to flow between the attic, basement/crawl space, and the interior walls.

You might also find the following links helpful:

http://www.buildingscience.com/search?SearchableText=air+barrier
http://www.buildingscience.com/resources/vapor_barrier_code_changes

These are just a couple results from a quick Google search--there's a lot of information out there.

Answer (score 0):

Many things/materials can be considered an air barrier. The thing to keep in mind, whatever your particular situation is, is that warm air holds more moisture than cold air. And that there is a temperature at which warm air when it starts to cool loses the moisture it can no longer hold. This temperature, called the dew point typically happens inside of an open cavity wall. The goal in the air barrier is to keep that warm air from meeting the cold air at the dew point. This is what the plastic vapour barrier with it’s taped and sealed seams is working to do. This is an easy solution when the walls are open, but not so much post construction. Drywall itself is fine as an air barrier. The problem areas will be any poorly constructed seams and all mechanical penetrations.

Many opportunities to get creative. As long as you keep in mind the mechanisms at play you can find nifty solutions. Perhaps most solutions that your local building inspector will not approve, but keep in mind the building science and there are usually ways to remediate.

Answer (score -1):

10 years late to this thread. Vapor barriers aren't remotely necessary.  Granted I'd highly suggest using plastic as it stops air flow which is what kills your energy bills. I've been remodeling homes since I was in diapers and I have never opened up a wall and found mold from anything other than a water leak from rain or plumbing. Thats walls with fiberglass insulation, blown in, none at all and even newspaper and newspaper alone just pasted to the exterior wall. and there was no moisture damage and this was in indiana where the summers are routinely in the 90s with 100% humidity and freezing winters. If you see any mold ever just spray it with a bleach and water mix and walk away. Don't wipe it don't anything it but walk away. When you come back the next day it will look like it was never there. Hope this helps going forward if by chance in hell you ever see it.

Comment: A little bit of formatting would help make this more readable.

Comment: OP is not asking if it is necessary, they are asking if it is possible.